# How to get array index when doing unnest in PGSQL

Tags: postgresql, unnest

I need to fetch array index when doing unnest. I tried row_number() Over() but this is calculating row number, not the array index. I also tried WITH ORDINALITY but it worked only with from clause.

```
select id, unnest(fname), status 
from testunnest;
```

**Rows in Table testunnest**

```
112w,{john,sam},yes  
2wew,{josh,Nick,Jeny},no
```

**The above query is returning result as**

```
112w    john    yes  
112w    sam     yes  
2wew    josh    No  
2wew    Nick    No  
2wew    Jeny    No
```

**Expected is**

```
112w    john    yes 1  
112w    sam     yes 2  
2wew    josh    No  1  
2wew    Nick    No  2  
2wew    Jeny    No  3
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

use the `unnest()` function in the `from` clause, then you can add the `with ordinality` option which returns the array index

```
select t.id, u.name, t.status, u.idx
from testunnest t
  cross join unnest(t.fname) with ordinality as u(name, idx);
```

In general it's recommended to use set-returning functions in the FROM clause anyway.